# To calculate the order of the group of all invertible linear operators on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field $F$ , then how can we calculate the order of the group of all invertible linear operators on $V$  in terms of $|F|$ and $\dim V$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: take a small example e.g. $V = (\mathbb{Z} /2)^2$ over $F = \mathbb{Z} / 2$, then calculating the number of invertible $F$-linear operators on $V$ is the same as counting the number of $\dim(V) \times \dim(V)$ matrices with coefficients in $F$ whose determinant is nonzero (or equivalently, such that there is no $F$-linear relation between the columns of the matrix). In this case, we have $|F|^2 - 1$ choices for the first column and $|F|^2 - |F|$ choices for the second column. How might this generalize?